# Why do I need addEventListener for my proto-element but not my dom-element in Polymer?

Tags: html, dom, polymer

So I'm learning polymer through the Firefox browser and I was running into the Polymer not defined error.  When researching SO I saw I have to wrap my script in the addEventListener function.

```
<link rel="import"  href="https://polygit2.appspot.com/components/polymer/polymer.html">

<script>
  // register a new element called proto-element
  //This example needs this eventlistener

  addEventListener('WebComponentsReady', function() {
  Polymer({
    is: "proto-element",

    // add a callback to the element's prototype
    ready: function() {
  this.textContent = "I'm a proto-element. Check out my prototype!"
    }
});
})
</script>
```

Now when I run it in the browser it works fine. When moving on to the DOM element, it seems my script no longer needs to be wrapped in addEventListener().

This works:

```
<dom-module id="dom-element">

 <template>
    <p>I'm a DOM element. This is my local DOM!</p>
 </template>

<script>
   //for some reason this example does not 
   //addEventListener('WebComponentsReady', function() {
  Polymer({
    is: "dom-element"
  });
//})
</script>

</dom-module>
```

So my question, why does my proto-element need the addEventListener function and my dom-module does not?

Answer (score 0):

This behavior can be explained with polyfills for web components, which are (at this point) still necessary for Firefox. In particular, [HTML imports](http://webcomponents.org/polyfills/html-imports/) need to be polyfilled, which is accomplished by the `webcomponents-lite.js` script (missing in your examples).

In your first example, you don't actually have to wait for the `WebComponentsReady` event to make a call to the `Polymer()` function, but for the `HTMLImportsLoaded` event. Because, it's at *that* point that the browser knows what to do with the link tag:
`<link rel="import"  href="https://polygit2.appspot.com/components/polymer/polymer.html">`. It then imports the Polymer library and you can make the call to `Polymer()`. Check out this [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/vuyigiguve/edit?html,output) showing how this works.

In your second example, the browser at first doesn't know what to do with the `<dom-module>`, because this is an element [from the Polymer library](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/blob/master/src/lib/dom-module.html) and not part of the HTML specification. So, `<dom-module>` is only available *after* the HTMLImports event has fired. Once the polyfills kick in, the `<dom-module>` is upgraded, the template is rendered and the script inside it is executed. In other words there's no need to wait for this event explicitly, because the upgrade can only happen after the event has fired (or if it's supported natively, as in Chrome).

This is my interpretation, but maybe the Polymer team can clarify it further...